# Deep learning Model

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Is this model good in terms of Accuracy? Test accuracy is better than training. Training accuracy = 98.55% and Test accuracy = 99.16%.[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is this model good in terms of Accuracy?

This depends on your data set. You should compare against a simpler model (a.k.a., a baseline) if you want to assess whether it's useful to use a neural network.